Find intersection of columns from different polars dataframes
I have a variable number of pl.DataFrames which share some columns (e.g. symbol and date). Each pl.DataFrame has a number of additional columns, which are not important for the actual task.
The symbol columns do have exactly the same content (the different str values exist in every dataframe). The date columns are somewhat different in the way that they don't have the exact same dates in every pl.DataFrame.
The actual task is to find the common dates per grouping (i.e. symbol) and filter each pl.DataFrame accordingly.
Here are three example pl.DataFrames:
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["AAPL"] * 4 + ["GOOGL"] * 3,
        "date": [
            "2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04",
            "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04",
        ],
        "some_other_col": range(7),
    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["AAPL"] * 3 + ["GOOGL"] * 5,
        "date": [
            "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04",
            "2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-05",
        ],
        "another_col": range(8),
    }
)

df3 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["AAPL"] * 4 + ["GOOGL"] * 2,
        "date": [
            "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-05",
            "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04",
        ],
        "some_col": range(6),
    }
)
DataFrame 1:
shape: (7, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_other_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 0              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 3              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 4              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6              │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

DataFrame 2:
shape: (8, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ another_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64         │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 3           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 4           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-05 ┆ 7           │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘

DataFrame 3:
shape: (6, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-05 ┆ 3        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 4        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 5        │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────┘

Now, the first step would be to find the common dates for every symbol.
AAPL: ["2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04"]
GOOGL: ["2023-01-03", "2023-01-04"]
That means, each pl.DataFrame needs to be filtered accordingly. The expected result looks like this:
DataFrame 1 filtered:

shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_other_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 3              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6              │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

DataFrame 2 filtered:
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ another_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64         │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6           │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘

DataFrame 3 filtered:
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 4        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 5        │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────┘


You can use pl.DataFrame.join() with how="semi" parameter:

semi Returns rows from the left table that have a match in the right table.

on = ["symbol","date"]
df1.join(df2, on=on, how="semi").join(df3, on=on, how="semi")
df2.join(df1, on=on, how="semi").join(df3, on=on, how="semi")
df3.join(df1, on=on, how="semi").join(df2, on=on, how="semi")

shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_other_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 3              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6              │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ another_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64         │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6           │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 4        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 5        │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────┘

Or you could probably generalize it a bit:
on = ["symbol","date"]
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# filter first dataframe on all others
for df in dfs[1:]:
    dfs[0] = dfs[0].join(df, on=on, how="semi")

# then filter all others on first one
for i, df in enumerate(dfs[1:]):
    dfs[i] = df.join(dfs[0], on=on, how="semi")

for df in dfs:
    print(df)


This works perfectly, thanks. I've got a follow-up question: How could I align the dates within each group in any individual dataframe, i.e. the dates for every symbol in a dataframe must be identical?

You can find the intersection with joins:
on = ["symbol", "date"]

intersection = (
   df1
    .select(on)
    .join(df2.select(on), on=on)
    .join(df3.select(on), on=on)
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       │
│ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ str        │
╞════════╪════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 │
└────────┴────────────┘

And use join again to "filter":
intersection.join(df1, on=on)
intersection.join(df2, on=on)
intersection.join(df3, on=on)

shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_other_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 1              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2              │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 3              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5              │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6              │
└────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘

shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ another_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64         │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1           │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 5           │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 6           │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘

shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date       ┆ some_col │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ str        ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-02 ┆ 0        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 1        │
│ AAPL   ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 2        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-03 ┆ 4        │
│ GOOGL  ┆ 2023-01-04 ┆ 5        │
└────────┴────────────┴──────────┘


Your solution seems to be correct, even with some huge real world dataset. Can you please elaborate (maybe with a toy example) why it is necessary to join intersection a second time ("filter")?

Well the second joins will "drop" / "filter out" rows not contained in the intersection from each frame e.g. AAPL,2023-01-05 in df3 - I'm not really sure what extra example I could add to what is already here.
